# Scriptella - Date format conversion not working

Tags: scriptella

I am having a problem in date format conversion while I am exporting data from MySQL to CSV.
I am using scriptelaa.1.1, the latest one I guess.

Here is my **etl.properties** file:

```
driver=mysql
url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/<my_DB_name>
user=<user_name>
password=<password>
classpath=/path/to/mysql-connector-java-5.1.19.jar;
```

here is my **etl.xml** file:

```
<!DOCTYPE etl SYSTEM "http://scriptella.javaforge.com/dtd/etl.dtd">
<etl>
    <description>Scriptella ETL File Template.</description>
    <properties>
        <include href="/path/to/etl.properties"/> <!--Load from external properties file-->
    </properties>
<!-- Connection declarations -->
<connection id="in" driver="${driver}" url="${url}" user="${user}" password="${password}" classpath="$classpath">
</connection>
<connection id="out" driver="csv" url="report.csv">
    #Use empty quote to turn off quoting
    quote=
    null_string=\\N
    format.dob.type=date
    format.dob.pattern=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
</connection>
<query connection-id="in">
    SELECT * FROM test;
<script connection-id="out">
    $1,$2,$3,$4
    </script>
 </query>    
</etl>
```

**dob** is my column name in MySQL table, it is **datetime** type column there.
Now when I export the data from MySQL the time comes in the format **yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S**
But I want **yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss**, so I have used

```
format.dob.type=date
format.dob.pattern=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
```

As it is suggested scriptella.1.1 has the feature and to use it, in the following link:
http://scriptella.javaforge.com/reference/index.html

But it is not working.
Can anyone help me out.

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formatting rules are applied to the variable name, therefore exactly the same variable name should be used for both format description and the expansion placeholder. In your cause, try using $dob instead of the column number.

Comment: i would like to ask one more thing
the separator I am using is ',' but when I give that in the connection parameter it did not work. So i have to give specifically in the **script connection-id** as you can see. So is there any way to solve that ?

Comment: I have one more doubt regarding export to DB from CSV.
Say i want to do some data massaging over a column in CSV, where and how will I do that ?
Its a bit urgent.

Comment: The ``separator`` parameter only applies to the input or output file. The actual query or scripts are always comma-separated. In other words, for your case, you can change the output separator to a semicolon, but leave commas in the script.

Comment: Please elaborate what is ``data massaging``?

Comment: Say during import from MySQL to CSV I replaced null by '\N', now during export I want to replace '\N' by null again, how to do that ?
'\N' is null for Hive.